# How to correctly call this merge sort function?

Tags: c, sorting, struct

I am trying to implement this merge sort function to sort an array of structs in c. When I call the function my program exits early, I think this is because my array i am sorting is of type row_t* and needs to be row_t**, I am unsure on how to correctly malloc my data in order to achieve this.

```
//I have copied relevant bits of my code below

//this is the struct i am trying to sort by the value S
typedef struct 
{ 
    double rho, u, v, x, y, flux_u, flux_v, S;
} row_t;

//This is where i allocate the array i want to sort
row_t* linear_row_arr = (row_t*)malloc(sizeof(row_t)*100);

//this is where i try to call the function,
//linear_row_arr is an array of row_t, with 100 elements
merge_sort((void**)linear_row_arr, 99, row_array_s_comp);

//This is the function i am trying to call.
void merge(void** array, int n, int mid, int cmp(const void*, const void*))
{
    // (0) need extra space for merging
    void** tmp = malloc(n * sizeof(void*));
    void** left = array;
    void** right = array + mid;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int left_size = mid;
    int right_size = n - mid;
    // (1) perform the merge
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        if (j == right_size)
            tmp[k] = left[i++];
        else if (i == left_size)
            tmp[k] = right[j++];
        else if (cmp(left[i], right[j]) < 1)
            tmp[k] = left[i++];
        else
            tmp[k] = right[j++];
    }
    // (2) copy the merged array
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = tmp[i];
    }
    // (3) clean up
    free(tmp);
}

void merge_sort(void** array, int n, int cmp(const void*, const void*))
{
    if (n > 1) {
        int mid = n / 2;
        merge_sort(array, mid, cmp);
        merge_sort(array + mid, n - mid, cmp);
        merge(array, n, mid, cmp);
    }
}

int row_array_s_comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    row_t* ra = (row_t*)a;
    row_t* rb = (row_t*)b;
    // with int data we can just subtract to get the right behaviour
    return ra->S - rb->S;
}
```

When I run this the code exits early with no error message.

EDIT:

I tried using @Ian Abbott's solution and it produced a seg fault at my comparison function. Could it be that I used malloc instead of calloc to allocate the memory for my data?

```
// This is my function call
//100 elements of row_t*
merge_sort(linear_row_arr, 100, sizeof(row_t*), row_array_s_comp);
```

EDIT 2:
Thank you Ian, I have fixed my errors and now have a handy merge sort function at my disposal. I up voted your answer but it says it won be displayed publicly as i have less than 15 rep. If anyone needs it here is the final comparison function i used was

```
int row_array_s_comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    row_t* ra = (row_t*)a;
    row_t* rb = (row_t*)b;
    // with double data we can just subtract to get the right behaviour
    return (ra->S > rb->S) - (ra->S < ra->S);
}


and i called the function with

merge_sort(linear_row_arr, 100, sizeof(row_t), row_array_s_comp);
```

If anyone finds this useful feel free to upvote @Ians Abotts answer as it is correct but I can't.
Thanks again for your time!

Comment: You are passing a pointer to the first element of an array of `row_t` to something that expects a pointer to the first element of an array of `void *`. No wonder it doesn't work. I would recommend changing the `merge_sort` parameters to be like the standard library `qsort` function, passing the element size to the function and treating the elements to be sorted as arrays of bytes (using `memcpy` to copy them).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you point me in the direction of where to start with this? I didn’t write this merge sort and am not confident in how to implement what you said above.

Comment: By the way, your `row_array_s_comp` function doesn't sort by the `S` values properly. It is subtracting `double` and implicitly converting the result to `int`. If the absolute difference is less than 1, the function will return 0. I recommend using `return (ra->S > rb->S) - (ra->S < ra->S);`. This will return -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: I'm concerned that you changed the return type of the comparison function to `double` since that doesn't match the comparison function pointer in my `merge_sort` function. It is more conventional for the comparison function to return an `int`.

Comment: Ah, I returned the actual difference and then decided which was bigger outside the comparison function, i'll update my code to the convention now, then update the post.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't seg fault.  You define a pointer to a struct `row_t* linear_row_arr` and then cast it to a pointer to a pointer `(void**)linear_row_arr` so if the function tries to dereference the parameter it will be using the bits inside a double as a pointer and it will never point the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation of a top-down merge sort of an array, using parameters similar to `qsort`. Time complexity is O(n log n). It uses temporary storage of similar size to the input array.

```
/* Subroutine to merge two input arrays into an output array. */
static void merge(void *out, const void *pa, size_t na,
                  const void *pb, size_t nb, size_t elemsize,
                  int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    while (na != 0 || nb != 0) {
        if (na == 0 || nb != 0 && cmp(pa, pb) > 0) {
            memcpy(out, pb, elemsize);
            pb = (const char *)pb + elemsize;
            nb--;
        } else {
            memcpy(out, pa, elemsize);
            pa = (const char *)pa + elemsize;
            na--;
        }
        out = (char *)out + elemsize;
    }
}

/* Merge sort an array. */
void merge_sort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t elemsize,
                int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    size_t nbottom;
    size_t ntop;
    void *midp;
    void *bottom;
    void *top;

    if (nmemb <= 1) {
        /* Too small to sort. */
        return;
    }
    /* Sort the bottom half and the top half. */
    nbottom = nmemb / 2;
    ntop = nmemb - nbottom;
    midp = (char *)base + (nbottom * elemsize);
    merge_sort(base, nbottom, elemsize, cmp);
    merge_sort(midp, ntop, elemsize, cmp);
    /* Make temporary copies of the sorted bottom half and top half. */
    bottom = malloc(nbottom * elemsize);
    top = malloc(ntop * elemsize);
    memcpy(bottom, base, nbottom * elemsize);
    memcpy(top, midp, ntop * elemsize);
    /* Do a sorted merge of the copies into the original. */
    merge(base, bottom, nbottom, top, ntop, elemsize, cmp);
    /* Free temporary copies. */
    free(bottom);
    free(top);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, i tried implementing this and again i got a seg fault at my comparison function, i'll edit what i tried in my post.

Comment: @eyedea_ability I think that is because you used `sizeof(row_t*)` for the `elemsize` parameter. It should be `sizeof(row_t)` or `sizeof(linear_row_arr[0])`.